# Change Assembly Name in Project properties caused Dataset errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dataset

I changed my Assembly Name and RootNameSpace in Project Properties. After I run the project, it gives me more than 80 Errors. All the errors are of DataSet I added to the application.
One of an Error look like

```
Error5  Type 'DSSummary.DataTable1DataTable' is not defined.
```

An early reply will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to apply the same change in all of your project as well

Comment: How to do that. Even my Dataset are not opening.

Comment: Have checked on what line the error occurs? It'll likely give you a hint of what's wrong. And as JSON said, if you have multiple projects you need to reflect the changes in all of the related ones (either in code if they reference this, or in the project properties if they use the same namespace).

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of your code